# Epimorphisms from a free group onto a free group

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

Let $f:F_n\to F_m$ be an epimorphism ($n\geq m$). Then it is true that there is a basis $X=X_1\sqcup X_2$ in $F_n$ such that $f$ maps $\langle X_1\rangle$ isomorphically onto $F_m$, and maps $X_2$ to identity. One can probably deduce this statement from the Grushko-Neumann theorem, but somehow I cannot get an elegant proof of it.

I can see that by the Grushko-Neumann we can assume that $m=1$, and hence our epimorphism factors through the abelianization. And then an ugly linear algebra appears... Any suggestions how to make the proof slick?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you need Grushko-Neumann for this, you just need to know about the Nielsen reduction process.

Start with any (ordered) free generating set $Y = \{ y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_n \}$ of $F_n$ and then apply the Nielsen reduction process to the generating sequence $\phi(Y) = (\phi(y_1),\ldots,\phi(y_n))$ of the free group $F_m$. But carry out the reduction operations on $Y$ as well as $\phi(Y)$.

A t the end of the process you will have what you are looking for. The set $X_1$ will be the inverse image under $\phi$ of the resulting free generating set of $\phi(F)$, whereas $X_2$ will map onto the generators that get eliminated during the reduction process as being the identity element of $F_m$.

Comment: @mathreader: There is also a geometrical/topological verion of this proof, in which one starts with a map of roses that represents $f$, and then one carries out the Stallings fold process (which can sometimes be regarded as the topological analogue of the Nielsen reduction process), at the end of which one has to interpret the result.

Comment: Thank you, Derek Holt and Lee Mosher! It seems that there is an intrinsic difficulty here, which should be dealt with in an algorithmical way, either through Nielsen reduction or Stallings foldings or ad-hoc linear algebra for the case $m=1$.