# Surjection between free groups

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

Suppose we have two surjective homomorphisms $f_1,f_2: F_{n} \rightarrow F_{m} $ of free groups (so $n\ge m$). One can always find homomorphism $g:F_n \rightarrow F_n $ giving a commuting triangle - when can it be enhanced to be an isomorphism?

Comment: There exists such an isomorphism $g$ if and only if there is an isomorphism of $F_n$ that maps $\ker f_1$ to $\ker f_2$. I don't know whetehr that helps at all!

Comment: Isn't it trur that we can split $F_n$ as a free product $E*G$ where $f_1$ sends $G$ to zero and is isomorphism on $E$? Then we do the same for $f_2$ obraining $T*U$ and we just send T to E and U to G ?

Comment: I think your question is solved here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/950835/epimorphisms-from-a-free-group-onto-a-free-group

Comment: @MoisheCohen  Yes you are right, and I answered it!

Comment: Incidentally, there is a large body of literature describing equivalence classes of epimorphisms $G\to F_n$, where $G$ is a finitely generated group. The answer is interesting already when $G$ is a surface group.