# Epimorphism from $F_n$ to $F_{n-1}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups

$F_n$ is the free group of rank $n$. I know that it is possible to construct an Epimorphism $f: F_n \to F_{n-1}$. How is this done? (I also want to consider the case $F_2 \to \mathbb{Z}$ but maybe there is no difference in the argument.)

My thoughts: Maybe one can use the fact that $F_2$ contains the free group of rank $k$ for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$. This implies that $F_n$ can be viewed as a subgroup of $F_{n-1}$ for $n$ at least $3$.

Comment: How are you defining free groups? In general though, you just map your basis for $F_n$ to the basis of $F_{n-1}$ using an embedding of the basis for $F_{n-1}$ into a basis for $F_n$, and then do whatever you want to the remaining basis element. For example, if you are using presentations $F_n\cong\langle x_1, \ldots, x_{n-1}, x_n\mid-\rangle$ and $F_{n-1}\cong\langle y_1, \ldots, y_{n-1}\mid-\rangle$, then the map defined by $x_1\mapsto y_1, \ldots, x_{n-1}\mapsto y_{n-1}, x_n\mapsto 1$ works.

Comment: See also [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/950835/epimorphisms-from-a-free-group-onto-a-free-group).

Comment: I define free groups via reduced words. But yes, I think that works. I was confused about something but now I see it is very easy.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I do not think this is a duplicate. Here, the starting point is two free groups and we wish to construct an epimorphism. There, the starting point is an epimorphism, and we are required to show a specific property. (I guess the duplicate combine's with Freakish's existence answer to given the required construction, but it is a bit like overkill!)

Comment: Yes, it is not really a duplicate.

Comment: Yes, it is not really a duplicate, but certainly closely related. The OP says in the beginning that we can obtain an epimorphism  $f\colon F_n\rightarrow F_m$ for all $n\ge m$ ,because "there is a basis $X=X_1\sqcup X_2$ in $F_n$ such that $f$ maps $\langle X_1\rangle$ isomorphically onto $F_m$, and maps $X_2$ to identity."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Free groups have a very special property. Each $F_n$ has a set of generators $\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$, called free generators. These generators have the following property:

If $G$ is any group and $h:\{a_1,\ldots, a_n\}\to G$ is any **function**, then there is a unique group homomorphism $H:F_n\to G$ such that $H(a_i)=h(a_i)$.

With this property we can easily show that there always is an epimorphism $F_n\to G$ if $G$ has a set of at most $n$ generators (regardless of whether $G$ is free or not). And this in fact generalizes to free groups over arbitrary alphabets, not only finite.